# Fetching all ERC1155 tokens of a smart contract ( The smart contract is not the minter )

Tags: nft, erc-1155, eoa, alchemy-sdk

In my project, I encountered a situation where I needed to **fetch the ERC1155 tokens that a specific smart contract owns** ( Assuming that I have already transferred a bunch of ERC155 tokens to it from another smart contract )

Alchemy has already provided valuable solutions ( Alchemy SDK ) for fetching all NFTs of an address ( EOA ) or fetching a whole NFT collection. Still, my need is different now as my target owner is not an EOA but a smart contract itself.

Is there a solution to this? Or I should query the whole contract's events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Moralis, they have a [`getWalletNFTs`](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-wallet-nfts) API that can do just that.

Even though the input describes it as a wallet `address`, the fact is that it doesn't make difference whether you use an EOA or smart contract address. As long as it is a valid address then it should work just fine.

You can simply just `npm install moralis @moralisweb3/common-evm-utils` and add the following code with `address` and `chain` params ready.

```js
const Moralis = require('moralis');
const { EvmChain } = require('@moralisweb3/common-evm-utils');

try {
    const address = '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890';

    const chain = EvmChain.ETHEREUM;

    await Moralis.start({
        apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        // ...and any other configuration
    });

    const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.nft.getWalletNFTs({
        address,
        chain,
    });

    console.log(response?.result);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Yoseph. Your answer would be the most complete one if we add a conditional statement (!Moralis.Core.isStarted) for executing "await  Moralis.start()". 
If not applied, Moralis gives us an error for every time the component gets rendered, telling us "Moralis.start()" should be executed only one time

Comment: Glad to help! Ahhh yes that will be needed for best practice to avoid initializing the SDK multiple times, but yeah if it is already initialized and you call `Moralis.start` again then it will throw an error